# How to Insert into temp table Using SubQuery and Select from Temp table

Tags: sql-server, subquery, temp-tables

I am trying to insert this data into a temp table
When I add the piece to insert into my temp table with the second result set #Temp
I recieve an incorrect syntax error
Any Ideas?

`sql`

````
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Kaven>
-- Create date: <August 2020>
-- Description: Summary Report of [spRPWipManufactureProcessLogR1]
-- Owner : RpData.dll
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spRPWipManufactureProcessLogR2]
    @FromDate DATE = null,
    @ToDate DATE = null,
    @Location NVARCHAR(15) =null, --Dropdown  --CostCentre
    @Operation NVARCHAR(15) = NULL, -- Dropdown --WorkCentre
    @JobNumber nvarchar(15) = NULL
AS
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
BEGIN
--EXEC [spRPWipManufactureProcessLogR2] '20200201', '20200301'
    IF @Operation = ''
    BEGIN
    SET @Operation = null
    END
    IF @JobNumber = ''
    BEGIN
    SET @JobNumber = NULL
    END
    IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Temppp_WarehouseList') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN DROP TABLE #Temppp_WarehouseList  END

    SELECT StockCode
    INTO #Temppp_WarehouseList 
    FROM CompanyA..InvMaster 
    
      
    DECLARE 
    @wh_List NVARCHAR(1000),    
    @wh_List2 NVARCHAR(1000)

    SELECT @wh_List = STUFF((SELECT ',['+l.Warehouse+' QtyOnHand]' FROM CompanyA..InvWhControl l WHERE l.Warehouse IS NOT NULL FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
    SELECT @wh_List2 = STUFF((SELECT ',['+l.Warehouse+' QtyOnOrder]' FROM CompanyA..InvWhControl l WHERE l.Warehouse IS NOT NULL FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')

    --SELECT @wh_List 
    --SELECT @wh_List2  

    SELECT ProductID, 
    FromDate,
    ToDate, 
    QtyBUoM
    INTO #TempBuOM
    FROM Cetus.dbo.SMDemandForcastDailyHierarchy df
    JOIN dbo.SMDemandSourceTypeDef st ON st.pkDFSourceTypeID = df.fkSourceType 
    WHERE 
    df.DemandSource = st.pkDFSourceTypeID 
    AND
    df.Parent = st.pkDFSourceTypeID 
    AND FromDate <= GETDATE()
    AND ToDate >= GETDATE()
    SELECT * FROM #TempBuOM



   SELECT * FROM #Temppp_WarehouseList t  
   INNER join   
   (SELECT *   FROM
   (SELECT Warehouse+' QtyOnHand' 'WarehouseOnHand', Warehouse+' QtyOnOrder' 'WarehouseOnOrder', QtyOnHand,QtyOnOrder,   
   b.CostCentre AS 'Location',  
   --b.WorkCentre AS [Operation],   
  -- arc.Job AS [Job Number],   
   --FORMAT(CAST(CAST(s.Event AS XML).value('(/OperationTrackingLog/TimeStamp)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS DATETIME),'HH:mm:ss') AS [Operation Compeleted Time],
  -- CONVERT(VARCHAR, FORMAT(CAST(CAST(s.Event AS XML).value('(/OperationTrackingLog/TimeStamp)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS DATETIME),'yyyy/MM/dd'),100)  AS [Operation Compeleted Date],
  -- CONVERT(Date, CONVERT(date, arc.DTComplete))AS [Compeleted Date],
   df.ProductID AS 'Product ID',  
   m.Description AS 'Stock Code DESCRIPTION',   
   arc.QtyToMake AS 'Quantity To Make',  
   arc.QtyManufactured 'Quantity Manufactured', 
   df.QtyBUoM AS 'Daily Demand',  
   inv.QtyOnOrder AS 'Quantity On Order',  
   inv.QtyOnHand AS 'Stock Levels'
   INTO #TEMP -- Error comes here
   FROM Cetus..WIPManufactureProcessLog s    
   LEFT JOIN WIP..WipMaster_Arc arc ON s.JobId = arc.Job   
   JOIN CompanyA..InvMaster m ON arc.StockCode = m.StockCode   
   JOIN CompanyA..InvWarehouse inv ON m.StockCode = inv.StockCode   
   JOIN CompanyA.dbo.BomOperations bo ON m.StockCode = bo.StockCode AND bo.Operation = s.Operation   
   JOIN CompanyA..BomWorkCentre b ON bo.WorkCentre = b.WorkCentre    
   JOIN [dbo].SMDemandForcastDailyHierarchy df ON m.StockCode = df.ProductID   
   JOIN dbo.SMDemandSourceTypeDef st ON st.pkDFSourceTypeID = df.fkSourceType 
   --EXEC [spRPWipManufactureProcessLogR2] '20190101', '20200201'

   Where CONVERT(VARCHAR, FORMAT(CAST(CAST(s.Event AS XML).value('(/OperationTrackingLog/TimeStamp)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS DATETIME),'yyyy/MM/dd'),100)  
   BETWEEN ISNULL(@FromDate,CONVERT(VARCHAR, FORMAT(CAST(CAST(s.Event AS XML).value('(/OperationTrackingLog/TimeStamp)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS DATETIME),'yyyy/MM/dd'),100)) 
   AND ISNULL(@ToDate,CONVERT(VARCHAR, FORMAT(CAST(CAST(s.Event AS XML).value('(/OperationTrackingLog/TimeStamp)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS DATETIME),'yyyy/MM/dd'),100))


   --WHERE FORMAT(CAST(CAST(s.Event AS XML).value('(/OperationTrackingLog/TimeStamp)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS DATETIME),'HH:mm:ss') >= '2020-02-01'
   --AND FORMAT(CAST(CAST(s.Event AS XML).value('(/OperationTrackingLog/TimeStamp)[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS DATETIME),'HH:mm:ss') <= '2020-03-01 '  
   AND m.WarehouseToUse <>'AA'   
   AND b.WorkCentre = ISNULL(@Location,b.WorkCentre )
   AND b.CostCentre = ISNULL(@Operation,b.CostCentre )
   AND arc.Job = ISNULL(@JobNumber,arc.Job)   )p     
   PIVOT     (
   SUM(QtyOnHand) FOR WarehouseOnHand IN
   ([BB QtyOnHand],
   [16 QtyOnHand],
   [IS QtyOnHand],
   [MS QtyOnHand],
   [MH QtyOnHand],
   [AA QtyOnHand],
   [BC QtyOnHand],
   [PH QtyOnHand],
   [P4 QtyOnHand],
   [PL QtyOnHand],
   [CC QtyOnHand],
   [SR QtyOnHand],
   [TS QtyOnHand],
   [WW QtyOnHand])) AS pvt 
   PIVOT     
   (SUM(QtyOnOrder) FOR WarehouseOnOrder IN 
   ([BB QtyOnOrder],
   [16 QtyOnOrder],
   [IS QtyOnOrder],
   [MS QtyOnOrder],
   [MH QtyOnOrder],
   [AA QtyOnOrder],
   [BC QtyOnOrder],
   [PH QtyOnOrder],
   [P4 QtyOnOrder],
   [PL QtyOnOrder],
   [CC QtyOnOrder],
   [SR QtyOnOrder],
   [TS QtyOnOrder],
   [WW QtyOnOrder])) AS pvt2  GROUP BY  )
   AS z  on t.StockCode = z.[Product ID]

  ```sql```
````

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Added answers in case the #TEMP table is supposed to have the inner query rather than the final pivot results.

Note that the 'code' provided is there to show structure - you'll need to add the slabs of text from above and bug-fix those as normal. The below is to demonstrate how to fix the issue.

---

That INTO #TEMP is in the middle of a FROM statement (it's not actually the final select) and therefore doesn't work.

If want the final results (e.g., from the pivot) to be stored in the temp table, remove the current 'INTO #TEMP' and put it into the outer query e.g.,

```
SELECT   *
    INTO  #TEMP
    FROM (your whole pivot statement) AS a
```

or alternatively using a CTE

```
; WITH CTE AS
    (your whole pivot statement)
  SELECT *
    INTO #Temp
    FROM CTE
```

---

If, on the other hand, you want to store the results of the inner query (*not* the pivot) in a temp table, then

1. run that first (e.g., take out the inner query you have there, into its own statement)
2. use the #temp table in the bigger query

```
-- Initial creation of temp table (SQL extracted from your current code)
SELECT Warehouse+' QtyOnHand' (... and rest of fields)
    INTO #Temp
    FROM Cetus..WIPManufactureProcessLog s 
        (... and rest of from, and where clauses)
```

```
-- And then use that in your pivot
SELECT * 
FROM 
   (SELECT * 
   FROM #Temppp_WarehouseList t  
   INNER join #TEMP ON (... matching fields)
   ) p
PIVOT
   (pivot commands etc)
```